# Image not appearing after Kinect begins

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to overlay an image over a kinect video feed (using kinect 2.0, with updated SDK). I have the image imported to my resources folder (through visual studio) and in the XAML builder it appears, but when the program begins nothing appears but the video. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my XAML code for refernece

```
<Window x:Class="Bitness.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="700" 
    Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded"
    Closing="MainWindow_Closing">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumGreyBrush" Color="#ff6e6e6e" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectPurpleBrush" Color="#ff52318f" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectBlueBrush" Color="#ff00BCF2" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Image Source="Resources/Ball.png" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="200" />
    </Canvas>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid Name="CompositeImage">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            <Image Source="{Binding BodySource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />

        </Grid>

    </Viewbox>


    <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="statusBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="White" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}">
        <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding StatusText}" />
    </StatusBar>


</Grid>
```

Comment: The Canvas with the Image (with Ball.png) is below the Viewbox, due to the order they appear in your XAML. Change their order, or set their ZIndex property, or perhaps define rows in the Grid. The current `Grid.Row="1"` is ineffective, as there are no RowDefinitions.